# how to get the text of an item in JTree and pass its value to another class

Tags: java

Hey i am a newbie to JAVA i am working on a project and at this point i am stuck what i want to do is...I have made a JTree listing some items in it now i want to get text of a selected item of JTree, store it in a String object and pass it to another class where i can do further operations on it... 
Here's what i have tried

```
Demo d;    //creating object of the class where i want to pass the value 
String s;

tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener()
 {
      public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) 
      {
        node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.getPath().getLastPathComponent();



   System.out.println("You selected " + node);
    s=node.toString();
    d.getVal(s);   //getVal() is the method in class Demo which will receive                                             
                      my String object 
  }
});
```

as i run the program a null value is returned in getVal() rather than the Text of the JTree item please help..

Answer (score 0):

In the code i can't see any `d=new Demo(...);` (or similar to get an instance of `Demo`). Without that you just declare the variable d but you never create an instance of that class.

Comment: You either have to create a Demo instance beforehand, lets say Demo d=new Demo(); and hand it the selection at runtime: d.setString(s); OR you create the object at runtime like Demo d1=new Demo(s);

Comment: If it is allways the same Demo Object (like a controller) you could try to bind the element like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787386/javafx-binding-textarea-to-element-of-selected-treeitem-contained-in-treeview

Comment: Whats about the variable s? It is set correctly? Next, what would you like to achieve with the `Demo` class? Could you post that code here to help us understand whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

Its done i have initialized the constructor and passed the String object in it rather than passing it in the function..here's what I did

```
Demo d;    //creating object of the class where i want to pass the value 
String s;

tree.addTreeSelectionListener(new TreeSelectionListener()
 {
      public void valueChanged(TreeSelectionEvent e) 
      {
        node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) e.getPath().getLastPathComponent();



   System.out.println("You selected " + node);
    s=node.toString();
    d=new Demo(s);                                   

  }
});
```

Thanks everyone for your advice.... :-)